# re.sub replacing everything with the last item in the list

Tags: python, regex

Im trying to make a new line every time i find a word starting with a capital letter, here is my code:

```
import re


def new_line(name):
    fr = open(name, 'r')
    string = fr.read()
    new_list = []
    fw = open('output', 'w')
    c = 0
    m = re.findall('\s+[A-Z]\w+', string,re.MULTILINE)
    for i in m:

        j = str(i)
        l = re.sub('[A-Z]\w+','\n'+str(m[c]), string,re.MULTILINE)
        c = c+1
        print("These are the list items:"+j+"\n")



     print("STRINGY STRING BELOW!!!")
     print(string)
     print('/////////////////////////////////////////////')
     print("Output :\n"+l)
     print(m)
new_line('task.txt')
```

Desired output should be something like this :

These are the list items: Miss

These are the list items: Catherine

.
.
.

These are the list items: Heathcliff

And then the text with new lines added , instead of replacing every match with a \n and the match itself, the text is replaced with only the last item from list m

Like this:

Output :

I got

Heathcliff

Heathcliff and myself to

Heathcliff

Heathcliff; and, to my agreeable disappointment, she behaved infinitely better than I dared to expect.

Heathcliff seemed almost over-fond of

Heathcliff.

Heathcliff; and even to his sister she showed plenty of affection.

I didnt post the original input text as it's too long.

Comment: Why do you have an output file that you never write to?

Comment: The original idea was to write the new string to an output file, i havent gotten around to doing that yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my approach: use `re.sub` to search for white spaces followed by a capital letter. Replace that with the capital letter itself.

```
with open(name) as infile, open('output', 'w') as outfile:
    contents = infile.read()
    new_contents = re.sub(r'\s+([A-Z])', r'\n\1', contents)
    outfile.write(new_contents)
```

## Notes

- The paretheses in the pattern tells `re` to remember the text within
- the `\1` in the replacement text is what `re` remembered before

Comment: This solution is actually better than wenzul's answer for solving the task.

Comment: Yes , i see, this is the first time i've discovered that re.sub can remember the matches

Answer (score 2):

You could try this. It just prefixes each word (with capital letter) with `\n`.

```
>>> re.sub(r'\s+([A-Z])','\n\g<1>', "Heathcliff and myself to Heathcliff; to my")
'Heathcliff and myself to\nHeathcliff; to my'
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems reasonable , i will try it out

Comment: Ok, I have edited my post a little. Now it's more like @Hai Vu.

Answer (score 1):

Since the list contains only matches that will end up in the list m, you are constantly replacing any word starting with upper case in the document with what is in m[c], so after you've looped through, it will be the last name in the list.

Try stopping the loop after c = 1, c = 2 etc, and you will find all the names to be that number in the list.

Comment: What would be a proper way to replace them with their corresponding words in the list then ?

Comment: If your purpose is just to add `\n` after every capitalized word, then I suggest @wenzul's answer.

Answer (score 1):

re.sub() replaces all non overlapping ocurrences of your pattern.

What does that mean? See the following example:

```
  import re
  test_str = 'spam spam spam'
  print re.sub('spam', 'beans', test_str, re.MULTILINE)
```

will print

> beans beans beans

What this means is that your code is replacing all ocurrences of capitalized words in the string with your last word. That is why you're seeing 'Heathcliff' everywhere: it was the last capitalized word in your text